Difficulty using org.json.simple library in Java project in VS Code
My settings.json file
{
  "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
    "lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar"
  ],
  "java.project.sources": [
    "src"
  ],
  "java.project.classPath": [
    "lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar"
  ],
  "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
  "java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-11",
      "path": "/path/to/jdk-11",
      "default": true
    }
  ]
}

My .classpath file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="C:\Users\PANZA AKHILESHWAR\OneDrive\Desktop\weatherapp\src"/> <!-- Assuming your source folder is 'src' -->
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:\Users\PANZA AKHILESHWAR\OneDrive\Desktop\weatherapp\lib\json-simple-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <!-- Add more classpath entries as needed for other libraries or sources -->
</classpath>

Description of the Issue
I'm encountering issues while attempting to integrate the org.json.simple library (json-simple-1.1.1.jar) into my Java project in VS Code. The project involves fetching weather data from an API and parsing JSON responses for display in a GUI.
Specific Errors:
When compiling my project, I receive errors such as:
package org.json.simple does not exist
cannot find symbol for classes like JSONObject, JSONArray, and JSONParser.

Steps Taken:
Added json-simple-1.1.1.jar to my project's build path.
Updated VS Code's settings.json with "java.project.referencedLibraries": ["lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar"].
Additional Information:

Using Java SE 11.
The JAR file is located at C:\Users\PANZA AKHILESHWAR\OneDrive\Desktop\weatherapp\lib\json-simple-1.1.1.jar.
Confirmed the JAR file's existence and ensured there are no typos in the path specified in settings.json.


By the way, Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code

If you use an absolute path by add "java.project.referencedLibraries": ["C:\\Users\\PANZA AKHILESHWAR\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\weatherapp\\lib\\json-simple-1.1.1.jar"] to your settings.json, will it work?
